# Active Records text matching

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am trying to do some basic text matching in Ruby using active records.

```
Here is my code so far;

require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'
require 'pg'
require 'pry'
require 'FileUtils'

$config = '
adapter: postgresql
database: edgar
username: YYYYY
password:
host: 127.0.0.1'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load($config))
class Doc    < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Eightk < ActiveRecord::Base; end



directory = "disease"       #Creates a directory called disease
FileUtils.mkpath(directory)     # Makes the directory if it doesn't exists

cancer = Eightk.where("text ilike '%cancer%'")
death = Eightk.where("text ilike '%death%'")


cancer.each do |filing|     #filing can be used instead of eightks
    filename = "#{directory}/#{filing.doc_id}.html"
    File.open(filename,"w").puts filing.text
    puts "Storing #{filing.doc_id}..."


death.each do |filing|  #filing can be used instead of eightks
    filename = "#{directory}/#{filing.doc_id}.html"
    File.open(filename,"w").puts filing.text
    puts "Storing #{filing.doc_id}..."

    end
end
```

I have a long list of conditions I want to search for;

1. Is there a way for me to combine the search list. i tried 'cancer'|'death' but didnt have any luck
2. I would like to do an exact match to the words rather than ilike but don't know the command,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
keywords = %w(cancer death anotherone)
records = Eightk.where keywords.map{|w| "(text ILIKE '%#{w}%')"}.join(' OR ')

records.each do |filing|
  filename = "#{directory}/#{filing.doc_id}.html"
  File.open(filename,"w").puts filing.text
end
```

Otherwise you could use 'SIMILAR TO' or 'POSIX' http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP then you can use regular expressions.

eg

```
Eightk.where "text SIMILAR TO '%(#{keywords.join '|' })%'"
```

POSIX would allow you to do checks for start and end of words so that you could check for only a full word match (eg would match on `,death`, `death` or `death.` but not `deathbed` etc.

I'll leave the regex stuff for someone with greater regex-foo :)

Comment: Hi @BigFive thanks for this. Is there a way to match on the exact word rather than the similar to command in active records? My search is getting swamped